# Angular2 set style attribute

Tags: angular, attributes, interpolation

I am trying to set a style attribute with a variable in angular 8, but I can't get it to work.

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let appointmentSlot of timeslots; let i = index">
        <div ngxSlickItem class="cards-slot slick-slide animation-show-slide-up"
          style='{{"--animation-delay:" + i}}'>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
```

Can anybody explain why the style attribute is not printing ?

It seems that the property cannot be bound, because it is not safe. Is it possible to print it anyway ?

I found this to work:

```
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}      

  getStyling(index: number) { 
    const styleAttribute = "--animation-delay: " +  index;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(styleAttribute);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried binding to `NgStyle` instead? https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Comment: I literally need style="--animation-delay: 1" to be in the tag, so that my css can pick this up

Answer (score 0):

Could be a syntax issue.  You could check [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e9rt7m) which has example usage of style, [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). hth

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a function call to establish your styling as follows:

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let appointmentSlot of timeslots; let i = index">
    <div ngxSlickItem class="cards-slot slick-slide animation-show-slide-up"
      [ngStyle]="getStyling(i)">
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Typescript:

```
getStyling(index: number) { 
    return { '--animation-delay': index } 
}
```

Comment: That does not work. I literally need `style="--animation-delay: 1"` to be in the tag, so that my css can pick this up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the return string is unsafe and thus is not printed. You can overrule this with:

```
 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}      

  getStyling(index: number) { 
    const styleAttribute = "--animation-delay: " +  index;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(styleAttribute);
  }
```